# Ember data RecordArray load callback

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Somewhere in my ember controllers code i loading some data. It looks like this:

```
models = App.MyModel.find()
```

It returns `<DS.RecordArray:ember763>` and send AJAX. I need to add callback on this data loading.
Something like this doesn't work:

```
models.on 'didLoad', () ->
  console.log 'Loaded' #never triggers
```

How can i solve this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that when called with no arguments `App.MyModel.find()` returns a "live array". Semantically a "live array" is always loaded. Behind the scenes, Ember will query your server the first time `find()` is called on a model.

Instead, use `App.MyModel.find({})` to run a `findQuery` with no params. See this issue for more detail:

https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/735